# Auto clear data in Edit Page

Tags: admin-on-rest

I created a dialog that contains a Create Form inside a Edit Form.
When I click on "New relationship" button, the dialog will be shown, but I don't know why the `records` in Edit form also be cleared.

Before click show Dialog:
[image: Before click show Dialog]

When click show Dialog:
[image: When click show Dialog]

After click show Dialog:
  [image: After click show Dialog]

Here is my code:

```
export class CaregiverEdit extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        open: false,
    };
}

handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open: true});
};

handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({open: false});
};

render() {
    const style = {
        margin: 12,
    };
    const actions = [
        <FlatButton
            label="Ok"
            onClick={ this.handleClose }
        />,
    ];
    var id = this.props.location.pathname.split('/')[2];
    const propsCreate = Object.assign({}, this.props, { authParams : {resource : "rela", route : "create"},
        location : {pathname : "/rela/create"}, match : { path : "/rela/create", url : "/rela/create"}, resource : "rela" });
    return (
        <div>
            <Edit title={<CaregiverTitle />} {...this.props}>
                <SimpleForm>
                    <DisabledInput source="id"/>
                    <ImageField source="profile_photo" />
                    <TextInput source="profile_photo" />
                    <TextInput source="name" />
                    <TextInput source="email" validate={email}/>
                    <TextInput source="phone" />
                    <BooleanInput source="status" label="Active"/>
                    <CardTitle title="* Relationship" titleStyle={{'fontSize':'18px'}}/>
                    <RaisedButton label="New relationship" onClick={this.handleOpen} style={style}/>
                    <GridField uid={id} {...this.props} />
                    <Dialog
                        title="New relationship"
                        actions={actions}
                        modal={false}
                        open={this.state.open}
                        onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                        autoScrollBodyContent={true}>
                        <div>
                            <br/>
                            <Create {...propsCreate} title=" " actions="">
                                <SimpleForm  redirect={"/caregiver/" + id}>
                                    {/*<ReferenceArrayInput>*/}
                                    <DisabledInput source="user" defaultValue={id} label="Caregiver ID"/>
                                    <ReferenceInput label="Centre" source="centre" reference="centre" sort={{ field: 'name', order: 'ASC' }} allowEmpty>
                                        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
                                    </ReferenceInput>
                                    <DependentInput dependsOn="centre">
                                        <SubGenreInput source="current_group" optionText="label" optionValue="id" type="classgroup"/>
                                    </DependentInput>
                                    <DependentInput dependsOn="current_group">
                                        <SubGenreInput source="student_id" optionText="fullname" optionValue="id" type="student"/>
                                    </DependentInput>
                                    {/*</ReferenceArrayInput>*/}
                                    <RadioButtonGroupInput source="account_type"  defaultValue={10} choices={[
                                        { id: 10, name: 'Caregiver' },
                                        { id: 20, name: 'Guardian' },
                                    ]} optionText="name" optionValue="id" />
                                    <TextInput source="relationship" label="Relationship"/>
                                </SimpleForm>
                            </Create>
                        </div>
                    </Dialog>
                </SimpleForm>
            </Edit>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I recommend you add the coding language as a tag. Also images should be displayed in the question, not just linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because all forms in aor have the same name: `record-form`. I think that after a create operation, we send a `reset` action for the form in order to support the "save and create new" scenario. Please open an issue so that we can discuss this.

**EDITED AFTER DISCUSSION**:

The fastest solution would be to have an edition view for the `CareGiver` and another one for the `Relationship`. You mentioned an n-to-n relationship with an intermediate table. This complexity should be hidden from the client. That's the job of either your API or your `restClient`.

From the client point of vue, you would have 2 entities using `ReferenceArrayInput` to maintain references between them.

If you do want to have edition/creation like you described before, you'll have to implement your own react components, eventually using aor `restClient` to fetch/update the data.

Comment: I've already create an issues here: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/1016

Comment: My issue in Github have been rejected. Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?